# Data types with colons in function arguments leading to "error: expected expression before ‘int’"

Tags: c

I am refactoring some old C code which has a macro

```
#define MACRO(x) _Generic( (x), u8: 256, u16: SOME_CONST )
```

which fails with:
*expected expression before ‘u8’*

Here is an example I found here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/_generic-keyword-c/ , which fails with the same error

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#define geeks(T) _Generic( (T), char: 1, int: 2, long: 3, default: 0) 
int main(void) 
{ 
    // char returns ASCII value which is int type.  
    printf("%d\n", geeks('A'));  

    // Here A is a string. 
    printf("%d",geeks("A")); 

    return 0; 
}
```

```
# gcc test3.c -o test -std=c11
test3.c: In function ‘main’:
test3.c:6:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘_Generic’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     printf("%d\n", geeks('A'));  
     ^
test3.c:2:33: error: expected expression before ‘char’
 #define geeks(T) _Generic( (T), char: 1, int: 2, long: 3, default: 0) 
                                 ^
test3.c:6:20: note: in expansion of macro ‘geeks’
     printf("%d\n", geeks('A'));  
                    ^
test3.c:2:33: error: expected expression before ‘char’
 #define geeks(T) _Generic( (T), char: 1, int: 2, long: 3, default: 0) 
                                 ^
test3.c:9:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘geeks’
     printf("%d",geeks("A")); 
                 ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is `test`? That's what your whole question boils down to. Your compiler can't find it and neither can I.

Comment: Does it matter? It fails with
_error: expected expression before ‘int’_
so as far as I understand this is wrong with syntax, before even looking for test()

Comment: The compiler seems to think it matters...

Comment: Can you provide a working the reduced example with defined test at your own discretion?
main() should be the same.

Comment: Make a habit of reading the first compiler error and resolve that, before moving on to the next. That one being "implicit declaration of function ‘test’".

Comment: And no, we have no idea what "test" is supposed to be. It's some manner of magical entity. A placeholder for `_Generic` perhaps? We can only guess.

Comment: It is not C for sure.

Comment: Well `test` might be some magical macro which will convert this weird stuff to valid C, but it is hard to see how to me.

Comment: @P__J__ It is, if some "smart" person wrote `#define test _Generic` and then made their own garage standard integer types after that. Making your own secret macro language to replace readable C should be criminal...

Comment: OK guys just realized it was _Generic, it probably answers my question.

Comment: @dsjfghkjhg "somehow" isn't good enough.  We need to know **exactly** how, i.e. show the code that defines `test`.

Comment: @Lundin dont you know the rule? As weird macro as "better" havker :)

Comment: @dsjfghkjhg Sounds like you should get rid of `test` in favour for `_Generic` and also get rid of the custom integer types in favour for the `stdint.h` ones. Stick to standard C as far as possible.

Comment: Guys the problem is not absence of ```test``` but the error ```error: expected expression before ```

e.g. I found this example
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/_generic-keyword-c/

when I compile it with gcc -std=c11 it fails with exactly same errors:
_error: expected expression before ‘char’_

Comment: Is it possible to add a multi-line code block in a comment?

Comment: Please update your question with [mcve] and new information, and the question might get reopened.

Comment: updated minimal reproducible example

Comment: you cant replace `_Generic` with something you like. `_Generic` is a keyword. https://godbolt.org/z/TaY89B

Comment: Can't reproduce with the new code: https://ideone.com/FhGWJn . Is this the exact code you are running?  Is your compiler supporting c11?

Comment: @dsjfghkjhg it is fine: https://godbolt.org/z/ZezfHI

Comment: I am not sure I understand. You probably meant _Generic not _Generick?
I updated my initial question, the problem is clearly seen there and can be easy reproduced. Must be something simple.

Comment: I cant reproduce

Comment: `gcc --version`

Comment: So, the problem is in my compiler finally? I use gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36.0.1)
This is Linux 7.6

Comment: too old - upgrade

Comment: That's pretty old.. C11 support is not complete there, so maybe `_Generic` is not supported.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/fkdg6J  reproduced the problem. If the gcc version 10 is avaiable and you use 4.8 - you are many generations behind

Comment: Problem sorted. Now it is the time for the archaeologists :)

Comment: @P__J__ CentOS 7 is still on that version.  For some reason they never upgraded.

Comment: @dbush and that is the reason why almost everyone using it do  `yum -y install gcc-c++`

Comment: How gcc-c++ is different?
`# yum -y install gcc-c++`
`Package gcc-c++-4.8.5-39.0.3.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version`

Comment: I still cannot compile it even in latest VS
`1>------ Build started: Project: Project1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------`
`1>test.c`
`1> test.c(6,20): warning C4013: '_Generic' undefined; assuming extern returning int`
`1> test.c(6,20): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'`
`1> test.c(9,18): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'`
`1>Done building project "Project1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.`
`========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========``